# Help with a few tags (overly specific?)

Tags: discussion

I was cleaning up a few new tags and found a couple corner cases that might help resolve some big-picture questions on whether a tag is needed:

- Should every specific model number of hardware have it's own tag, or should that be limited to individual radios (or lines) and tag everything else with either manufacturer or a more general tag? [vgs-1](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vgs-1) has exactly one question, the same as [voice-keyer](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice-keyer), I think [vgs-1](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vgs-1) can be deleted because the issue is relevant to most hardware of that type, but also because there are enough different voice keyers that it would be better to tag all questions about them as [voice-keyer](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice-keyer) rather than ten or twenty different splinter tags.
- On the other hand, maybe something like [ts-590s](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ts-590s) might be okay? I'd rather see a tag for each "line" of similar radios, since there's so much similarity between (for example) a TS-820, TS-820S, TS-830, TS-830s, that they could all fit in a [ts-820-830](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ts-820-830) with a few cleverly placed synonyms.
- Is [vacuum-tube](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vacuum-tube) about vacuum tubes, or radios that use vacuum tubes? Anyone with a strong opinion one way or the other want to write a tag wiki?

Answer (score 5):

I think tags for model numbers are OK - it is *extremely* handy to be able to instantly pull up a list of all questions specifically discussing the same model radio as you have (or to filter a search to only questions discussing your radio). That said, I agree with WPrecht - these tags should be kept only for questions that are specific to a single radio.

I think that tags for 'lines' of radios are nigh-impossible to maintain - if we were to try to implement them, I'd bet that we'd wind up with a bunch of people just creating new single-model tags that would then have to be manually merged, which isn't something I think is worth spending the effort to do.

Re: [vacuum-tube](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vacuum-tube) - I'd say it's okay to use the tag for both the tubes themselves and for questions about radios that use them *which concern the tube component*. It shouldn't be applied to every single question about radios which happen to use tubes; only those where the fact that the radio uses tubes is actually relevant.

Answer (score 4):

I think a tag of a specific model number is appropriate if the question is specific to that model number. The problem is, as you point out there are also questions that are more broadly applicable too and this could lead to tag bloat with all the possibilities.  So far, we've gotten very few hardware specific questions, so we might just want to stick with the model numbers and revisit it as more questions come in.

Given that thought process, the tag vacuum-tube should apply to the tubes themselves with the radio model/brand tag specifying radios that use vacuum tubes.